# Having trouble fixing my hour timer interval?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im having a hard time figuring out how to calculate for hour in my timer app. When i run my app and set a time for (3 hours : 0 minutes : 5 seconds)the countdown i get is (3 hours : 80 minutes : 5 seconds)

I have been messing around with the hour variable which seems to be the cause of the problem. since the timer was working fine before adding the hour parameter.

```
//check if my hour const makes sense
const getRemaining = time => {
  const hours = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  const seconds = time - minutes * 60;
  return {
    hours: formatNumber(hours),
    minutes: formatNumber(minutes),
    seconds: formatNumber(seconds)
  };
};



//check if this makes sense for the hours
start = () => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    remainingSeconds: 
      parseInt(state.selectedHours, 10) * 60 * 60 +
      parseInt(state.selectedMinutes, 10) * 60 +
      parseInt(state.selectedSeconds, 10),
    isRunning: true
  }));


  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      remainingSeconds: state.remainingSeconds - 1
    }));
  }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason your are avoiding the built-in `Date` API? You don't have to do this yourself. Simply create a new Date object and use the API methods.

Comment: I can't understand your code. Its very badly formatted, you declare a function `getRemaining` but you never use

Comment: that because i took it from a sample code and wanted to add the hour parameter since it didnt have it.

Comment: @iagowp i do use it i just didnt post my entire js file.. i olny posted the two functions that i know is giving the error. which is the math in calculating the hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including remaining hours in your calculation of remaining minutes. So `minutes` results in a value of 180, which is truncated to "80" (probably by `formatNumber()`?)

To fix this, subtract the remaining whole hours from `time` before calculating minutes:

```
const getRemaining = time => {
  const hours = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60);
  time = time - hours * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  const seconds = time - minutes * 60;
  return {
    hours: (hours),
    minutes: (minutes),
    seconds: (seconds)
  };
};
```